# Wildcard searching in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-queryset

How can we do a wildcard searching in Django. If i am filtering username from a list in database, how is it possible to display the filtered data with those exact usernames or part of it.?

```
def filter(request):
    val3='' 
    if request.GET.has_key('choices'):
        val2=request.GET.get('choices')
    if request.GET.has_key('textField'):
        val3=request.GET.get('textField')
    if request.POST:
        val2=request.POST.get('choices')    
        val3=request.POST.get('textField')
    if val2=='Designation':                
        newData = EmployeeDetails.objects.filter(designation=val3) 
        flag=True 
    elif val2=='Name':
        newData = EmployeeDetails.objects.filter(userName=val3)
        flag=True 
    elif val2=='EmployeeID':
        newData = EmployeeDetails.objects.filter(employeeID=val3)  
        flag=True       
    elif val2=='Project':
        newData = EmployeeDetails.objects.filter(project=val3)   
        flag=True   
    elif val2=='DateOfJoin':
        newData = EmployeeDetails.objects.filter(dateOfJoin=val3) 
        flag=True       
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/employeeList/')
```

This is my function for filtering. Now its filtering with exact words. I want to display the userNames even if part of it is given for filtering. Please help me to solve this as i am new with Django

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using a less strict filter, like __contains:

```
elif val2=='Name':
        newData = EmployeeDetails.objects.filter(userName__contains=val3)
        flag=True
```

Docs: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#contains

Comment: But userName here is a field in table. It gives me this error "FieldError at /filter/

Cannot resolve keyword 'userName_contains' into field."

Comment: Are you using a single underscore between userName and contains? Lookups are prefixed by double underscores. At least that's what I figure from the error you posted.

Comment: well...that was exactly the error..i gave only 1 underscore..thanks a lot for your help..My problem is solved..:)

Comment: hey...i got 1 more doubt with this..is it not case sensitive ?

Comment: when i gave Joh for Johhny it worked..but when i gave joh for Johhny ir didnt work :(

Comment: Read the docs link, it has a lot of examples and more lookup types. For case insensitive filtering you can try: `__icontains`

Answer (score 7):

You can use `contains` query e.g.

```
Entry.objects.get(headline__contains='Lennon')
```

See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#contains

There are other options too like [startswith](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#startswith), [endswith](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#endswith), and you can do even [regex](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#regex) search on most databases.

Comment: @rv_k, other people have given examples based on your code, though I would recommend you to go thru django docs and tutorial first

Answer (score 1):

Probably [field lookups](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups) will help you here. It lets to filter by beginning of the word, containing word and so on.

Comment: for example: newData = EmployeeDetails.objects.filter(designation__contains=val13) or newData = EmployeeDetails.objects.filter(designation__startswith=val3)

Comment: when i tried doing like that, it gave me "Field Error'. Here designation, usernames are all field names in db