# How to do wildcard search for single character replacement ( _ ) in Django ORM?

Tags: python, django, django-models, wildcard, django-orm

I have a case where I need to do a wildcard search using Django ORM.

I have a column - `column1` which contains mobile numbers.

I need to do a wildcard search for a single character replacement which is `_` in `MySQL`.

I can do that like `Mobilenumbers.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM MOBILENUMBERS WHERE COLUMN1 LIKE '98765_7644')`. But how do I do that same thing in Django ORM.

This is **not** a duplicate of [Wildcard searching in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230200/wildcard-searching-in-django).

Comment: The single character wildcard in SQL is `%`.

Comment: I guess `%` represents `zero` or `more` characters. But not `exactly one character`.

Comment: @KlausD. `_` is a single character. `%` is multiple characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [**`__regex`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#regex), like:

```
Mobilenumbers.objects.filter(
    column1__regex=r'^98765.7644$'
)
```

You can even restrict this further to only allow digits as wildcard character:

```
Mobilenumbers.objects.filter(
    column1__regex=r'^98765\d7644$'
)
```

The `^` and `$` are the start and end *anchors* respectively to specify that the string starts with `987...`, and ends with `...644`.

The `\d` only matches digits. So that would mean that the last regex would match `9876547644`, but not <s>`98765a7644`</s>.

Comment: can I use this in combination with `contains`? like if `98765\d7644` returns all the numbers with `\d` replaced by 1 character between `98765`, `7644` and for `33\d`, it should return all the numbers starting with `33`?

Comment: @SukumarRdjf: you can omit the `^` and `$` anchors. For example `r'\d'` will return all records with a column that contains a digit. `^12` returns all records with `column1` that starts with `12`, etc.

Comment: Everything looked good until I came across that It should search across 50 million records and it takes too much time. Please let me know if there is any other way?